# Add column values after DataBind

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

I'm new in C# and i want to know how to calculate the sum of column after DataBind().
 Can anyone tell me how to create object of individual column because i'm calculating the sum of individual column and passing it to particular object of that column.

```
protected void LoadYearlyPurchaseData(DataTable PurchaseSummaryDatatable)
        {
            DataTable FormattedPurchaseSummaryTable = 
            GetFormattedPurchaseSummaryTable(PurchaseSummaryDatatable);
            PurchaseSummaryGrid.DataSource = FormattedPurchaseSummaryTable;
            PurchaseSummaryGrid.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: can you show FormattedPurchaseSummaryTable code?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
        var columns =new string[] { "column1", "column2", "column3" };
        object[] colSumObj = new object[columns.Length];
        for(int i=0; i<columns.Length;i++)
        {
            colSumObj[i]= TableName.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<int>(columns[i])).Sum();
        }
```

Comment: i've edited my question now. can you please tell me the solution. Sorry I was confused at first but now i know what i have to do